# Intellectual Property from old job

Tags: legal, intellectual-property, teamleader

I am a team leader at a tech company. Our team are currently building up a certain area of expertise. A colleague has joined us recently and has shared with me the Intellectual Property of the same area of expertise which belongs to his old employer.

Please confirm:

1. He is in the wrong legally and morally

Please advise:

1. Am I now an accomplice (Documents are littered with the old company name and copyright notes)?
2. Can we use the bad Intellectual Property with [Clean Room Design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design)
3. Do I need to raise this point to higher management?

Comment: How do you define "intellectual property" in this regard?

Comment: One thing I don't see explicitly mentioned: are those documents confidential or published? In both cases, they would have the company name and copyright notice.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> He is in the wrong legally and morally

**Yes, he is.** You should destroy these documents without reading them, and inform to him that you've done so. You should absolutely not use them in any way, shape or form, and you should absolutely file this chain of events (including the above actions) with upper management, so it's abundantly clear you did the correct thing if it ever comes back to bite you somehow.

Make sure you keep a copy of the above message in your own records, as well.

Separately to the above, you should consider very seriously whether you want to actually keep this employee on. If he's done that to his old company, he's likely to do it to you as well.

Answer (score 4):

> Please confirm: He is in the wrong legally and morally

Most would agree that passing on confidential information without permission is morally wrong. I am not a lawyer, but it seems very likely he is legally in the wrong too. Consult a qualified lawyer if you want to be sure.

> Am I now an accomplice (Documents are littered with the old company name and copyright notes)?

It seems unlikely (again, ask a lawyer) that you'd be an accomplice just because someone sent you some documents, that's out of your control. However, if you asked for, read, keep, or in any way use the information in those documents, then you may well be. So don't do that.

> Can we use the bad Intellectual Property with Clean Room Design

Ask a lawyer.

> Do I need to raise this point to higher management?

Yes. This employee has displayed dishonesty to the point of gross misconduct (imagine how you and management would feel about it if he'd done this in the opposite direction, moving from you to the other company). You need to escalate this, you need to be prepared for the possibility that your colleague may be fired, and you need to be ready to prevent him from taking your company's property with him when he goes.

Answer (score -1):

Speaking from a US/Western perspective.

1. Is he morally or legally reprehensible for his actions.

The answer is maybe and depends a lot on what type of intellectual property is at issue?  Is it published documents subject to copyright law, trade secret information, source code brought from the former employer?  How do you know these are confidential documents?  Just because they are copyrighted does not make them unshareable information that cannot / should not be used.

For example, consider a book that you purchase at a book store.  The book is likely copyrighted and almost always has the publisher's name prominently displayed on the cover as well.  That doesn't prevent you from giving the book to a friend as a gift or selling it on eBay.

---

1. Are you now an accomplice

You're not an accomplice, but you might be guilty of a crime.  For example, there is criminal liability in the US for having knowingly received a trade secret (18 USC s. 1832).

2. Can you use the intellectual property if you then participate in clean room design?

If the information is trade secret information, anyone that receives the information is considered "contaminated" regardless of whether they develop their own solution independently.  If the information is just copyrighted, it depends on how the information has made available by the author.

3. Should you raise the issue to management?

You should never hesitate to ask a boss, especially one with whom you have a good rapport, his or her thoughts on the issue.  That said, it is not at all clear to me from what you said that your fellow employee had or shared materials that he shouldn't have.

Comment: The reason that you can resell a physical book is due to the "first sale" principles which exist in both EU and US law - but these apply only when the product has been *sold* to you in the first place. It is remarkably unlikely that the documents in question here were sold.

Comment: "Just because they are copyrighted does not make them unshareable information that cannot / should not be used" - are you quite sure that you understand what copyright means?

Comment: @mawg:  I'm quite certain that I do.  Copyrighted restricts performance or reproduction of a work *in full* as copyrighted.  It does not prevent reuse of the ideas and teachings of that work.  For example, a poem that "substantially transforms, modifies, or adapts" the original copyrighted work does not violate the original copyright.

Comment: @PhilipKendall:  first sale *does not* require the exchange of money.  A copyright-holder can give away copyrighted information freely and yet still retain a copyright.  A freely-given, but copyrighted document, can still be shared with others.